# Join table in HNibernate mapping issue

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have second code in my .hbm.xml file:

```
  <class name="Option" table="tOptions">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="Id" sql-type="int"/>
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="DocumentId" column="Ref"/>
    <property name="QuoteRef"/>
    <property name="OptionCode" column="OpCode"/>
    <property name="Description" column="Description"/>
    <property name="SupplierID" column="SupplierID"/>
    <property name="OptionTypeId" column="OptionType"/>
    <join table="tActiveOffers">
      <key column="Ref" unique="true"/>
      <property name="Colour" column="ExteriorColor"/>
      <property name="Trim" column="InteriorColor"/>
    </join>
  </class>
```

Seems normal, but when I'm trying to get something from database, I'm receiving an error:
"invalid index 11 for this sqlparametercollection with count=11", which, in most cases points on NHibernate problems. Also, all worked fine until 2 new fields (Colour and Trim) were added to Option class. So I think that the problem lies in incorrect join.

It will work fine if key column will be equal to Id

```
<join table="tActiveOffers">
  <key column="Id" unique="true"/>
  <property name="Colour" column="ExteriorColor"/>
  <property name="Trim" column="InteriorColor"/>
</join>
```

but this is not good for me (Ids are not the same thing it two tables).

I guess that there is a problem with incorrect key or something else.

What I am missing and how could it be done more correctly?

**Edit:**
Error Stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.RangeCheck(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.Int32Type.Set(IDbCommand rs, Object value, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.OnAutoFlush(AutoFlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.AutoFlushIfRequired(ISet`1 querySpaces)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.List(IQueryExpression queryExpression, QueryParameters parameters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionQueryImpl.List()
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that the key column does not target the id, but some property, we have to use `property-ref`, so instead of this: `<key column="Ref" unique="true"/>` use this

```
<join table="tActiveOffers">
  <key column="Ref" unique="true" property-ref="DocumentId"/>
  <property name="Colour" column="ExteriorColor"/>
  <property name="Trim" column="InteriorColor"/>
</join>
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, I'm still getting this strange "invalid index 11 for this sqlparametercollection with count=11" but at least my mapping is fine now.

Comment: This exception is during the insert.. right? are you sure that your DocumentId is really having some value? and also, is your mapping snippet 1:1?

Comment: Em, no. This exception appears when I'm trying to get values from databases. DocumentId always have values. And sorry, didn't get what do you mean by snippet 1:1...

Comment: Well, exactly same scenario is working for me, so I would like to ask you, extend your answer with full stack, please... that would help

Comment: I really didn't understand you. Full stack of what? Anyway, I putted my join into <!-- --> tags and everything works fine, so I guess that error are definitely somewhere inside Nhibernate.

Comment: of your exception... there is almost always clear answer. so please, provide us with your full outuput of your exception... clear?

Comment: oh, sorry, I was thinking about other thing. Added error stack trace.

Comment: Oleg, this is not full information. But in general, I can for **sure say** `invalid index` exception is always related to wrong mapping. Very often: one column is mapped twice... but it is NEVER issue when querying... it could be. Perfectly ok. But for WRITE it will be the issue! and while your stack is not complete, I can clearly see **` NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()`** as part of it! So you are definitely calling WRITE operation.... not sure if I can help you more without more detailed info. the above is NOT sufficent... sorry

Comment: ...again can understand, sorry. Something more than stack trace? Do you mean InnerException? If yes - InnerException is null. Source is System.Data. Data is System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.

Comment: I summarized that all in the comment above

Comment: Well, I'm told already that this is definitely mapping :) And also I have a little theory... maybe I am wrong but so far my mapping tries to join assuming that Id = Ref but this is not. Also Ref in tActiveOffers are not UniqueKey.

Comment: Look at your comment above *...Em, no. This exception appears when I'm trying to get values from...*, you have to decide what is really happening. Are you getting data or persisting... the problem in fact would be easy to solve, if you will provide the really correct info

Comment: Figured it out. It wasn't problem with hibernate mapping. I had a corrupted data in my table. At least, your code example helped me to fix overall mapping issue. Thanks:)

Comment: Great to seeeeee that ;) great ;) Good luck with NHibernate, which is awesome tool ;)